# Рандомная запись в страницу NAND Macronix

Tags: c++, c, embedded

Пытаюсь осуществить случайные чтение и запись в NAND.
Делаю все по AC waveform указанной в даташите (http://www.macronix.com/Lists/DataSheet/Attachments/2670/MX30LF1G08AA,%203V,%201Gb,%20v1.5.pdf)

```
struct IORequest_t {
    void*    buffer;
    uint16_t ofst;
    uint16_t size;
};    

ResultCode_t
NandBase::Write(uint32_t addr, IORequest_t *requests, uint32_t cnt) {
    /// Вычисляем адрес страницы в микроосхеме
    uint32_t pageNumber = addr / NAND_PAGE_SIZE;
    addr = pageNumber << 16;

    /// Дождаться готовности микросхемы
    if(WaitReady() != RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        return RESULT_TIMEOUT;
    }

    /// Отправляем команду записи
    *(uint8_t* )(MapAddress | COMMAND_SECTION) = 0x80;//CMD_PAGE_WRITE;   

    /// Отправить адрес
    *(uint32_t* )(MapAddress | ADDRESS_SECTION) = addr;


    /// Записываем данные
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        const uint8_t* src  = (const uint8_t*) requests[i].buffer;
        uint16_t ofst = requests[i].ofst;
        uint16_t size = requests[i].size;

        /// Проверяем не выйдет ли запись за предел страницы
        if(ofst+size > NAND_PAGE_SIZE) {
            return RESULT_INVALID_PARAMS;
        }

        /// Отправить команду произвольного доступа
        *(uint8_t* )(MapAddress | COMMAND_SECTION) = 0x85;//CMD_PAGE_WRITE;

        /// Отправляем смещение
        *(uint16_t*)(MapAddress | ADDRESS_SECTION) = ofst;

        /// Пишем данные
        for(const uint8_t* data = src; size; size--) {
            *(uint8_t*)(MapAddress | DATA_SECTION) = *data++;
        }

    }

    /// Отправляем команду подтверждения записи
    *(uint8_t* )(MapAddress | COMMAND_SECTION) = 0x10;//CMD_WRITE_CONFIRM;

    /// Дождаться готовности микросхемы
    if(WaitReady() != RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        return RESULT_TIMEOUT;
    }

    /// Проверить результат записи
    uint8_t status;
    ReadStatus(&status);
    if(status & 1) {
        return RESULT_PROGRAM_FAILED;
    }

    /// Отправить коману чтения
    *(uint8_t* )(MapAddress | COMMAND_SECTION) = 0x00;//CMD_PAGE_READ;

    /// Отправить адрес
    *(uint32_t* )(MapAddress | ADDRESS_SECTION) = addr;

    /// Отправить команду подтверждения
    *(uint8_t* )(MapAddress | COMMAND_SECTION) = 0x30;///CMD_READ_CONFIRM;

    /// Дождаться готовности микросхемы
    if(WaitReady() != RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        return RESULT_TIMEOUT;
    }

    /// Чтение каждого блока данных
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        const uint8_t* src  = (const uint8_t*) requests[i].buffer;
        uint16_t ofst = requests[i].ofst;
        uint16_t size = requests[i].size;

        /// Отправить команду рандомного доступа
        *(uint8_t*)(MapAddress | COMMAND_SECTION) = 0x05;//CMD_RANDOM_DATA_OUTPUT;

        /// Отправить смещение
        *(uint16_t*)(MapAddress | ADDRESS_SECTION) = ofst;

        /// Отправить команду подтверждения рандомного чтения
        *(uint8_t*) (MapAddress | COMMAND_SECTION) = 0xE0;//CMD_RANDOM_DATA_OUTPUT_CONFIRM;

        /// Сравнить исходняе и записанные данные
        for(const uint8_t* data = src; size; size--) {
            if(*data++ != *(uint8_t* )(MapAddress | DATA_SECTION)) {
                return RESULT_PROGRAM_FAILED;
            }
        }
    }

    return RESULT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Пишу в предварительно стертый блок, проверка чтением всегда проваливается: читаются единицы.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вопросы: обмен в принципе работает? Т.е. id у Вас корректное приходит? Линейные чтение-запись работают? Контроллеру внешней памяти от (uint32_t*) плохо не становится? Я ни разу не пробовал так, всегда руками преобразовывал к байтам. Правда, я и писал всегда ровно одну страницу, формируя её заранее "внутри".